# Possible to chain commands using xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I'd like to put a sleep between ea of the calls to curl:

```
ssh someone@somehost "cd /export/home/someone && find . -name '*' -print| xargs -n1 curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT"
```

Not sure it can be done. Have tried dozens of permutations. Can get a sleep at beginnning/end but not between.
Many Thanks

Comment: can you not just do `first command ; sleep 10 ; second command` or `first command && sleep 10 | second command` if you have to pipe ?

Comment: Why do you need the sleep? Also, it seems like `find /export/home/someone -exec curl -u someone:password -vT {} ftp://somehost/tmp/` would work as well.

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4, you don't even need `find`: `shopt -s globstar; curl -u someone:password -vT /export/home/someone/**/*`

Answer (score 3):

xargs accepts a single command. You need to get that single command to do two things.

Try

```
| xargs -n1 bash -c 'curl ... "$0"; sleep ##'
```

or (to use the "normal" positional arguments you need to fill in `$0` manually).

```
| xargs -n1 bash -c 'curl ... "$1"; sleep 1' -
```

Comment: I might have over-interpreted the rather telegraphic question, but I had the impression that they don't want to sleep at the beginning or the end, only in between.

Comment: @rici I think you over-interpreted the request. I think the point there was that they could already get a sleep at the start *or* the end of the series but not in between the calls (to effect a delay between requests, like `wget -w`) and not that a sleep at the start/end was unacceptable. But your interpretation is certainly much more difficult to pull off.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting part of this question is getting the sleeps between the curls, and not at either the beginning or the end of the sequence of curls.

If you don't have too many files, for some value of "too many" [Note 1]

```
find . -type f --exec bash -c '
    doit() { curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT; }
    doit "$1"; for f in "${@:2}"; sleep 2; doit "$f"; done
    ' _ {} +
```

I changed the `find` criteria from `-name *` (which will match all files and directories) to `-type f`, which will only match regular files.

The above command line works by using `find` to invoke (with `--exec`) an explicit subshell (`bash -c`) passing it a large number of filenames as arguments (`{} +`). (The `_` is because the first argument to `bash -c script` is taken as `$0`, not `$1`.) The script provided to `bash -c` just loops through its arguments, using the convenience function `doit` (which you can easily redefine in case you want to use this idea with a different command.)

It's possible that you didn't really need `find` because you don't actually care about recursive matching, in which case you could simplify that a bit. Also, with bash 4 you get to use `**` for recursive globbing, although `**` will match subdirectories as well, so you'd need to filter those out.

Here's a bash 4 example:

```
doit() { curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT; }
shopt -s globstar
sleep=
for f in **; do if [[ -f $f ]]; then
  $sleep
  doit "$f"
  sleep="sleep 2"
fi done
```

**Notes:**

1. Unfortunately, the maximum number of files is system dependent, and depends on the amount of memory available for arguments and environment variables (and consequently on the total size of the environment variables). On my system (Ubuntu), the maximum is around 128 kilobytes of filename, which is probably several thousand files unless you use really long filenames. If you exceed this limit, the `bash -c` invocation will be executed more than once, and there will not be a sleep before the second and subsequent invocations, which means that one file in every several thousand will uploaded without a prior sleep. On the other hand, the sleeps along for 2000 files add up to more than an hour, so I don't suppose it is very likely that this restriction applies.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `xargs` you could use a subshell:

```
ssh someone@somehost 'cd /export/home/someone && find . -name "*" -print| (while read file; do curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT "$file"; sleep 10; done)'
```

Note that I also flipped your single and double quotes so that the local shell doesn't try to interpret `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
ssh someone@somehost "cd /export/home/someone && find . -name '*' -print |
  parallel -j1 'sleep 10;curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT'
```

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop in that.

```
ssh someone@somehost "for i in `ls`; do curl -u someone:password ftp://somehost/tmp/ -vT ; sleep 10;done"
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Just let the shell glob it for you. `for i in *;`.